# Apache2 mod-jk and VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-jk

I have an apache2 server with few virtual host. Two of those Virtual Hosts is using modJK to handle pages generated by Glassfish. 
I have global configuration for modJK and JkMount directives used only in VirtualHost sections.
Generally this configuration works, but sometimes (quite often) I get 503 error when I'm trying to access those Glassfish pages.
I don't know how to find a reason of that (maybe some hits ?), but I changed log level for modJk to debug.
And I saw entries like this:

```
jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3773): missing uri map for domainWithoutJkMount:/viewtopic.php
```

This is an entry for request that is handled by PHP, and the Virtual Host for this domain has no **JkMount**.
So as I understand the documentation **modJK** shouldn't send anything from this VH to modJk.

Why I can see those entries in log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think modJK is outdated and not reliable.

I messed with it a time ago and would recommend to just use apaches `mod_proxy`, which is really easy to configure and just works.

Uninstall `mod_jk` and install `mod_proxy`, the put something like the following in your vhost configuration file:

```
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

assuming that your glassfish's aquarium is located on localhost port 8080. If the error still occurs, there must be something wrong within your glassfish instance.